# <**> is a variant of <*> with the arguments reversed. What does "reversed" mean?

Tags: haskell, operators, terminology, applicative

[In `GHC.Base` the description of `<**>` runs:](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#%3C%2A%2A%3E)

> A variant of `<*>` with the arguments reversed.

It is widely known that "reversed" in that case does not mean "flipped" as:

```
GHCi> [1, 2, 3] <**> [(^2), (+1)]
[1,2,4,3,9,4]
GHCi> [(^2), (+1)] <*> [1, 2, 3]
[1,4,9,2,3,4]
```

So, what does "reversed" mean?

---

**Side note: there are applicative functors which have `(<**>) = flip (<*>)`. For example, here is my proof for the reader (`(->) e`):**

```
(->) e: f <**> g =
    = liftA2 (flip ($)) f g =
    = (flip ($) <$> f) <*> g =
    = \e -> ((flip ($) . f) e) (g e) =
    = \e -> flip ($) (f e) $ (g e) =
    = \e -> (g e) $ (f e) =
    = \e -> g e (f e) =
    = g <*> f. => (<**>) = flip (<*>).
```

Comment: Side note to your side note: functors such that `(<**>) = flip (<*>)` are known as commutative applicative functors (or commutative monads, if they happen to be monads as well).

Comment: possibly better description could be "A variant of `<*>` with the arguments' *roles* reversed."

Comment: @WillNess agreed. Truth be told, I would have gone even further writing some kind of a relation between `<*>` and `<**>` down, like this one: `xf <**> ff = (&) <$> xf <*> ff`. It would also add more clearance to the definition, as the right hand **IS** the definition, just in terms of `<*>`, not `liftA2`: `liftA2 f xf yf = f <$> xf <*> yf`.

Comment: some like `liftA2` better; `(<*>) = liftA2 ($)` and `(<**>) = liftA2 (&)` are  perfectly nice and clear. and short. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recently added [`do`-notation to the *base* documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:-60--42--42--62-) which makes it easier to compare `<*>` and `<**>`, notice how both of them run left-to-right and both of them return `f a`:

```
  fs <*> as
=
  do f <- fs
     a <- as
     pure (f a)
```

and

```
  as <**> fs
=
  do a <- as
     f <- fs
     pure (f a)
```

It is known and [codified (`Control.Applicative.Backwards`)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Applicative-Backwards.html#t:Backwards) that applicatives can be run backwards , I have to cut this answer short. Li-yao Xia's answer with liftA2 ($) and liftA2 (&)

Answer (score 7):

If we stay at the example of lists we can see through your examples how `<**>` behaves reverse.

The expression `as <**> fs` means something like

```
foreach a in as {
    foreach f in fs {
        add (f a) to result;
    }
}
```

and `fs <*> as` means something like

```
foreach f in fs {
    foreach a in as {
        add (f a) to result
    }
}
```

So `as <**> fs` results in `[f1(a1), f2(a1), ..., fn(a1), f1(a2), ..., fn(a2), ...]`

And `fs <*> as` result in `[f1(a1), f1(a2), ... , f1(am), f2(a1), ...]`

So the order of the *loops* is reversed.

Comment: yes! Functors are generalized loops `[ f x | x <- xs]`; Applicatives are generalized *nested* loops `[ (x,y) | x <- xs, y <- ys]`; Monads are generalized *dynamically created* nested loops `[ (x,y) | x <- xs, y <- k x]`.

Comment: or we could choose another base, with `fmap f xs = [ f x | x <- xs]`, `ap xs ys = [ x y | x <- xs, y <- ys]`, `join xs = [ y | x <- xs, y <- x]`. all these written with MonadComprehensions of course.

Answer (score 6):

One way to illustrate it symbolically is to compare their expressions in terms of `liftA2`:

```
(<*>)  = liftA2 (\f x -> f x)
(<**>) = liftA2 (\x f -> f x)
       = liftA2 (flip (\f x -> f x))
```

Comment: I guess that is what I used proving the equivalence of `<**>` and `flip (<*>)` for the reader.

Comment: Perhaps use `($)`?

Comment: @dfeuer well, as far as I know, `$` cannot be used in `Control.Applicative`. I guess it’s up to us whether we want to follow this rule outside the library or not.

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor, is that some sort of joke? There might (I don't know) be issues using `($)` in `GHC.Base`, but I can't imagine it's a problem elsewhere.

Comment: @dfeuer From Control.Applicative: >NOTA BENE: Do NOT use `($)` anywhere in this module! The type of `($)` is
slightly magical (it can return unlifted types), and it is wired in...

You can view the full text if you follow the link I enclosed with my question in the first line (the first note in the module). The authors warn us about not using `$` right under the definition of `<**>` once again.

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor, that warning is in `GHC.Base`, not `Control.Applicative`. Note that the `Applicative` typeclass and `<**>` are defined in `GHC.Base`. There's certainly no need to worry about it anywhere outside that module.

Comment: @dfeuer you are right, sorry - did mistook the link for some reason. I edited the post. Nonetheless, the module in which the operators are defined contains the warning :).